# Error en al hacer build en Eclipse: Could not delete .svn

Tags: eclipse

Cuando intento hacer un `build` en Eclipse recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/xxx/WEB-INF/classes/.svn'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing the project and building it since it may be inconsistent.

He probado haciendo el `clean` y el `refresh`, pero nada, sigue ahí el error. Y como no puedo hacer el `build` no sé si mis cambios están bien o no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Árbol del proyecto:

Lo siento pero no puedo dar mas información que esta del árbol

Proyecto

----carpeta de paquetes

--------paquetes

------------clases

----html

--------carpetas

------------.jsp

----web-inf

--------carpetas

------------carpetas

----------------contenido

La carpeta `.svn` que me pide borrar esta dentro de contenido, la carpeta contenedora se llama `com` que a su vez esta dentro de `WEB-INF`

Answer (score 1):

Como se indica en esta [respuesta de Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40459385/3695983) para un problema similar, puedes solucionarlo de dos maneras diferentes:

1. Mueve/Borra el directorio .svn fuera del árbol del proyecto
2. Crea un árbol sin versionar a partir del Working Copy (svn help export) e importa ese proyecto.

El modo adecuado es que .svn debe existir en todos los directorios **menos** en los de `output`. La razón es porque no debes hacer check-in o out de los ficheros compilados, sólo de los ficheros con código fuente.

Comment: Buenas gracias por ayudar, el problema es que una vez borrada esa carpeta me pone lo mismo con otra, que no puedo borrar porque forma parte del proyecto. ¿que puedo hacer?

Comment: Añade más información a la pregunta: incluye el árbol del proyecto y qué carpeta .svn estás borrando.

Comment: He añadido a la pregunta el esquema del árbol con el que trabajo